# Why don't future humans use nano-genes?

Tags: doctor-who

In [*New Earth*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Earth) we see "The Sisterhood" (which are the future of human healing). This is about 50 billion years in the future, but a seemingly way better healing system was devised in only about 3000 years (5100); I'm referring to the nano-genes we see in [*The Empty Child*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Empty_Child) and [*The Doctor Dances*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doctor_Dances).

So my question is why don't future humans use nano-genes? Did they lose the technology due to the Doctor's "visit" there?

Comment: After a little chat with tryingToGetProgramming, we agreed to fill this problem under "The writers didn't care very much about coherency", which is often the case in this show :)

Comment: Because "Are you my mommy?" is scary...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Humanity never really got the nano-genes technology to begin with, since the Doctor destroyed it before departing, as described in [*The Doctor Dances*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doctor_Dances) wikipedia page:

> Meanwhile a German bomb falls onto the site, but Jack uses his ship to capture it and hauls it out into space. Then the Doctor sets the medical transport to explode once everyone is safely far from it, thus destroying the technology and matching the historical records of an explosion at the site.

This explain this apparent regression. If left intact, this technology would have modified the Earth's timeline quite heavily: we are talking about the Penicillin era :)

Comment: then where did captain jack get it?

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight It falled from the sky before _The Empty Child_, causing the Situation of the Week: Jack Harness knew that this event would occur, and his own original plan whas to sell it rather to let it be destroyed by a bomb: All is explained in the two episodes recaps ;)

Comment: no, jack had other nano-gene's he healed rose's rope burns with, and he didn't even know that the "warship" had nano-genes until the end of The Doctor Dances.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight Yes, since his ship was alien future tech too, but Jack Harness is not the whole humanity (even if he would probably like to "dance" with all of it).

Comment: yes, but if they had *some* nano-gene's in 5100 wouldn't **5 billion** years be enough to make it mainstream? (lol)

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight All the informations we have are synthetized [there](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Nanogene). Apparently some novel author made himself the same reflection than you, since they are shown used in the _Peacemaker_ Doctor Who novel, but not in the show itself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12104/discussion-between-eureka-and-tryingtogetprogrammingstraight)

Answer (score 1):

In the Doctor Who episode "[Utopia](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/29-11.htm)" the Doctor refers to the human race periodically backsliding into physical forms that *resemble* modern humanity (in between their various attempts to become pure energy or thought, etc)

> **DOCTOR:** *Don't you see that? The ripe old smell of humans. You survived. Oh, you might have spent a million years evolving into
> clouds of gas, and another million as downloads, but **you always revert
> to the same basic shape. The fundamental humans**.*

There's no immediate reason to assume that a technology that was designed to work on 50th Century humans would be effective on human beings from the 100000000000000th Century, merely because they look similar.

Comment: it seems to be made to be able to adapt to *any* life-form

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight - Any *current* lifeform. Who knows what differences there are between modern humanity and a reformed humanity billions of years into the future.